# What is the nth term of this exponentially increasing sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Me and my friend occasionally set each other difficult maths problems to solve and my friend seems to have stumped me this time.

He gave me a sequence and told me to find a function for it e.g $f(n) = n^{2+n}$ He said that it didn't use recursion (no $f(n) = f(n-1)$) and that it didn't involve exponentiation or powers (no $n^{3}$). This is the sequence:

$$5, 21, 138, 1710, 30285, 665343$$

and that's all he gave me. I hope you can help me! Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to look pretty? I have a pretty ugly polynomial solution that would suffice.

Comment: At a glance, the ratios between terms are ~4, ~6, ~12, ~18, and ~22, and after the first pair, each term has factors in common with the previous one.

Comment: If the formula is a polynomial it is greater than degree 4. (The fifth set of differences is not constant). With 6 numbers in the sequence that is the highest degree polynomial that you can check, by that method. As Dando16's answer shows with 6 numbers in the sequence you can create a fifth degree polynomial that yields the sequence. I'm guessing that's not what your friend had in mind - because there's no redundancy in the sequence WRT to polynomial. Hence no way to check if formula is what your friend had in mind. And because there's a fairly prescribed way to generate that polynomial.

Comment: Well, I guess the one who comes with the prettier function wins.

Comment: BTW, @Steven's observation shows that the 6 numbers are super exponential. If they were exponential then the ratios would be more or less constant. And FWIW, $n^n$ is not exponential. It is tetration - repeated exponentiation (double arrow in Knuth's notation). Exponentiation would be $c^n$ where $c$ is a constant - repeated multiplication (single arrow in Knuth's notation).

Comment: @zwim whoever comes up with the closest formula to what my friend has wins.

Comment: @Caird $n^3$ is a power of $n$. $3^n$ is exponentiation. More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation). And $n^n$ is tetration.

Comment: @Χpẘ thanks for the clarification! Updated accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If you don't necessarily care how it looks,

$$ f(n) = \frac{264\,869}{60}n^5 - \frac{172\,547}{4}n^4 + \frac{1\,784\,209}{12}n^3 - \frac{841\,047}{4}n^2 + \frac{1\,504\,739}{15}n + 5 $$

provides your desired solutions (with $f(0)=5$) and gives the next few terms $f(6)=3\,570\,034$, $f(7)=12\,020\,916$, $f(8)=31\,437\,693$, ...

Comment: While it may produce the correct answer, it uses exponentiation $n^5$ (and you've made it $f(n)$ but have used $x$ in your formula)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing the $x$'s were a typo and I've fixed it. Generally exponentiation refers to the variable in the exponent. Is this perhaps what your friend meant? Just looking at how those points points grow I doubt there's a linear solution.